# CodeFight firstDuplicate interview challenge

Tags: algorithm

As per problem statement:

> Write a solution with O(n) time complexity and O(1) additional space
>   complexity. Given an array a that contains only numbers in the range
>   from 1 to a.length, find the first duplicate number for which the
>   second occurrence has the minimal index. In other words, if there are
>   more than 1 duplicated numbers, return the number for which the second
>   occurrence has a smaller index than the second occurrence of the other
>   number does. If there are no such elements, return -1

I followed my code according to constraints and still I'm getting time complexity error. Here's my solution:

```
int firstDuplicate(std::vector<int> a)
{
    long long int n = a.size();
    int cnt=0;
    for(long long int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        //cout<<a[i]<<"      "<<cnt<<endl;
        if(a[i]==n||a[i]==-n)
        {    cnt++;
            if(cnt>1)
                return n;
        }
         else if(a[abs(a[i])]<0)
            return -a[i];
        else
            a[a[i]] = -a[a[i]];
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Can anyone suggest me better algorithm or whats wrong with this algorithm?

Comment: If you want help debugging your program, you have to say what's wrong with it. That might involve finding test cases for which it doesn't do what's expected or is too slow. That some website produces a "time complexity error" isn't sufficient.

Comment: @PaulHankin the code fails for very large value of n in range 10^5. I can't provide a test-case here. No doubt the above code runs successfully over given test cases(upto range 10^3 - 10^4.

Comment: Perhaps run the code on small test cases and check for out-of-bounds array accesses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The algorithm for this problem is as follows:

> For each number in the array, `a`, each time we see that number, we make `a[abs(a[i]) - 1]` negative. While iterating through `a`, if at some point we find that `a[abs(a[i] - 1]` is negative, we return `a[i]`. If we reach the last item in the array without finding a negative number, we return `-1`.

I feel like, this is what you were trying to get at, but you might have overcomplicated things. In code this is:

```
int firstDuplicate(std::vector<int> a)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < a.size(); i += 1)
    {
        if (a[abs(a[i]) - 1] < 0)
            return abs(a[i]);
        else
            a[abs(a[i]) - 1] = -a[abs(a[i]) - 1];
    }

    return -1;
}
```

This runs in O(n) time, with O(1) space complexity.

Comment: Thanks It works!! But mine one and and your's seem same to me except I use array from 1 to n-1 with extra counter variable to keep track of nth variable. Can you point out my error?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the indexes to mark whether an element has occured before or not, if the value at idx is negative then it has already occurred before

```
int firstDuplicate(std::vector<int> a)
{
    long long int n = a.size();
    int cnt=0;
    for(long long int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        int idx = a[i] - 1;
        if(a[idx] < 0){
            return a[i];
        }
        a[idx] *= -1;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: here's link for the problem statement https://codefights.com/interview-practice/task/pMvymcahZ8dY4g75q